# Как построить путь между двумя точками на плоскости (не обязательно кратчайший)?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графы

У меня есть граф с вершинами в виде координат на плоскости (x, y) и несколькими ребрами, показывающими связи между координатами.

[image]

Как можно построить путь по координатам (не обязательно кратчайший), зная связи между координатами?
Пример:

[image]

Если фиолетовая клетка расположена на координатах (1,2) и синяя на (4,0), то нужно как-то построить красную прямую так, чтобы выглядела как на скриншоте под номером 1 или 2, но не 3. То есть как получить координаты красных клеток?

EDIT:
Нашел [Алгоритм Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0), но там как раз 3 вариант со скриншота. Еще это кратчайшее расстояние, но есть ли какой-то алгоритм с не кратчайшим путем, а, например, путь к клетке по полукругу или по полуквадрату?

Comment: Просто модифицируй Брезенхема. При изменении целой части крась не только очередной квадрат на строку ниже, но и предыдущий в той же строке. Получишь вариант 2. Или не предыдущий, а в этой колонке на обеих строках - получишь вариант 1. *есть ли какой-то алгоритм с не кратчайшим путем* Разве что с промежуточными точками - но при этом построение просто распадается на несколько независимых.

Comment: Можно идти по горизонтали а потом по вертикали. Заодно он и кратчайшим будет.

Comment: Есть ещё [волновой алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Ли)

Comment: Это классическое применение 2d BFS, путь будет работать и с препятствиями, и он будет и кратчайший

Задача на эту тему https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1193

И решение https://cses.fi/paste/1163a96667b1693e2d9aad/